# Are packaged DAGs in Airflow "isolated"

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Deploying a DAG to Airflow using [packaged zip](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#packaging-dags) works well. It also looks like you could isolate the code in each zip. By that I mean, you could have one version of dependency classes in one zip, and another version in another zip. Both deployed in the same Airflow, and they won't interfere with each other.

So far, this has worked well when testing it on a local running Airflow (1.10.15). But I've once seen this not to be true, when deployed on GCP Composer. Then suddenly the one of the packaged DAGs was using code from the other DAG, rather than code found within the zip. But when I tested it again, it does as follow "isolation" of the code.

So, is it so that one can "isolate" code using packaged zips? Or does the quote from the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#packaging-dags) tell otherwise:

> They will be inserted into Python’s sys.path and importable by any other code in the Airflow process, so ensure the package names don’t clash with other packages already installed on your system.

Comment: I was not able to replicate the non-isolated behaviour that you observed and I think this behaviour roots from Airflow 1.x and not Cloud Composer. So it would be better to open a bug in Apache Airflow github and provide reproduction steps here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues

Comment: Also, the Airflow community released Airflow 2.x and might not have plans to release any new version of Airflow 1.x. Thus, reproduction should preferably be done in Airflow 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @KabilanMohanraj. I have actually not able to reproduce myself, so I was hoping someone with the knowledge of the inner workings of the DAG processor had the answer. Before I start creating infrastructure based on a wrong assumption :) Maybe I'll ask in an Github issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer this myself. The short answer is no, it does not work that way.

It is due to the way zips are loaded in the DagBag class. This results in very random code being chosen as the code to use. Ref https://github.com/astronomer/airflow/blob/4cfb3aa75dd9f169801e797e343d9cb5844a2053/airflow/models/dagbag.py#L369.

Now, that first being said, the closest workaround is this [Airflow Packaged Dags (zipped) clash when subfolders have same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744582/airflow-packaged-dags-zipped-clash-when-subfolders-have-same-name/59372645#59372645)